# Plesk Login Page ERROR: Uncaught Error: Class 'Form_View' not found in /opt/psa/admin/plib/PleskException.php:69

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plesk

When I try to open the Plesk Login Page via :8443 I get the Error:

```
ERROR: Uncaught Error: Class 'Form_View' not found in /opt/psa/admin/plib/PleskException.php:69 Stack trace: #0 /opt/psa/admin/plib/PleskException.php(34): psaerrorForm(Object(Error)) #1 /opt/psa/admin/plib/PleskException.php(13): report_crash('Class 'HTML' no...', Array, 'Error', 500, Object(Error)) #2 [internal function]: plesk_exception_handler(Object(Error)) #3 {main} thrown (PleskException.php:69)
```

I've nothing changed at the Server or Plesk. The Frontend works. It's running on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it with commands:

plesk installer --select-release-current --reinstall-patch --upgrade-installed-components

plesk repair installation